# Stationary state - PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, definition, mathematical-modeling

Supose the following PDE in $x$ and $t$:

> $u_t+(t+1)u_x=u_{xx}-2$

I know that stationary state is the solution when $u_t$ (dependence of time is $0$). So, can I also consider $t=0$ (getting the problem $u_x=u_{xx}-2$)? I mean, if the definition of stationary state is related whit the independence of time, could I consider any time fixed? It seems a little strange. For example, if I have:

> $u_t+(t-1)u_x=u_{xx}-2$

What time should I get? Note that $t=0$ and $t=1$ lead to really different equations, $u_x=u_{xx}-2$ and $0=u_{xx}-2$.

Many thanks.

Comment: I think a more robust definition is to check if $u(t,\cdot)$ admits a limit $v(x)$ when $t \to + \infty$ for all $x$ and if yes, what is the PDE that verifies $u$.

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand very well. Is this the definition of stationary state? Many thanks.

Comment: what are the boundary and initial conditions?

Comment: I am not sure there is a universal definition of stationary state for all PDEs... As you pointed out, the presence of $(t+1)$ in your PDE makes the stationary state - if it exists -  hard to find because one cannot simply take $u_t = 0$. The only strategy i can think about is to solve the PDE and study what happens when $t \to + \infty$, if the solution converges to a stationary state.

Comment: @Héhéhé, solving PDE taking $u_t=0$ I got $u=\dfrac{c_1 e^{(t+1)x}}{t+1}-\dfrac{2x}{t+1}+c_2$, which converges to $\infty$, right? Many thanks!

Comment: @mathstackuser12, in fact I do not have initial conditions once this example I invented and is not exactly what I have to do (to preserve ethics with professor)... So, I'd like just to think about the process. Many thanks.

Comment: No no you have to solve the full PDe with $u_t = 0$.

Comment: Do you mean that I do not should take $t$ fix? Many thanls